# Instantiating Jersey's LoggingFeature with maxEntitySize of 0

Tags: java, logging, jersey, dropwizard

I'm using Dropwizard 0.9.0 with Jersey to spin up a RESTful web service. I'm using the `LoggingFeature` class to log requests and responses. Note that I'm also calling the [constructor that accepts the `maxEntitySize` parameter](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/2.25.1/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/logging/LoggingFeature.html#LoggingFeature(java.util.logging.Logger,%20java.util.logging.Level,%20org.glassfish.jersey.logging.LoggingFeature.Verbosity,%20java.lang.Integer)).

In that Javadoc, it states that negative numbers for the `maxEntitySize` parameter are treated as `0`. However, what does a value of `0` for `maxEntitySize` actually indicate? The constructor's Javadoc doesn't state what it means and neither does the description of `Max entity size` in [Jersey's logging chapter](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/logging_chapter.html#d0e15694). Google is equally vague on this one.

Is the value of `0` synonymous with setting it to the value of [`LOGGING_FEATURE_MAX_ENTITY_SIZE`](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/2.25.1/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/logging/LoggingFeature.html#DEFAULT_MAX_ENTITY_SIZE) or the value of [`DEFAULT_MAX_ENTITY_SIZE`](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/2.25.1/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/logging/LoggingFeature.html#DEFAULT_MAX_ENTITY_SIZE) or something else entirely?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The purpose of `maxEntitySize` is to specify how many bytes of response (in case of client) you want to print in the logs.

For example, if you specify it 10, then it will print only 10 bytes of response and then print ...more...

Below is one example -

```
Apr 14, 2017 1:04:27 PM org.glassfish.jersey.logging.LoggingInterceptor log
INFO: 1 * Client response received on thread main
1 < 200
1 < Content-Length: 23
1 < Content-Type: application/json
1 < Date: Fri, 14 Apr 2017 04:04:27 GMT
{"id":101,...more...
```

Note that last line contains actual response and it prints only 10 bytes

If you specify 0 or negative value, then it will not print response -

```
Apr 14, 2017 1:06:08 PM org.glassfish.jersey.logging.LoggingInterceptor log
INFO: 1 * Client response received on thread main
1 < 200
1 < Content-Length: 23
1 < Content-Type: application/json
1 < Date: Fri, 14 Apr 2017 04:06:08 GMT
...more...
```

Note that last line only contains ...more... . There is no response data at all.